# Why blockcypher send transaction is throwing fatal error?

Tags: transactions, sending

I am trying to send bitcoin implementing blockcypher API, but having difficulty in using the following code snippet...

i. http://blockcypher.github.io/php-client/sample/doc/transaction-api/CreateTransaction.html

ii. http://blockcypher.github.io/php-client/sample/doc/transaction-api/CreateAndSignAndSendTransaction.html

The transaction is being created perfectly, but following error is being thrown while trying to send it...

**Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'BlockCypher\Exception\BlockCypherSignatureException' with message '1 private keys do not correspond to any input. Please check private keys provided.' in /www/myserver.com/blockcypher1/php-client/blockcypher/php-client/lib/BlockCypher/Api/TXSkeleton.php:148 Stack trace: #0 /www/myserver.com/blockcypher1/php-client/blockcypher/php-client/lib/BlockCypher/Api/TXSkeleton.php(96): BlockCypher\Api\TXSkeleton->generateSignatures(Object(BlockCypher\Crypto\PrivateKeyList), 'btc') #1 /www/myserver.com/blockcypher1/php-client/blockcypher/php-client/lib/BlockCypher/Client/TXClient.php(35): BlockCypher\Api\TXSkeleton->sign(Array, 'btc') #2 /www/myserver.com/blockcypher1/send.php(19): BlockCypher\Client\TXClient->sign(Object(BlockCypher\Api\TXSkeleton), Array) #3 {main} thrown in **/www/myserver.com/blockcypher1/php-client/blockcypher/php-client/lib/BlockCypher/Api/TXSkeleton.php** on **line 148**

But, I have provided unencrypted Hex private key of my input address. Also tried with WIF. None is working! How do I solve this ?

Comment: Is the key the right key for at least one of the inputs?

Comment: @NickODell Yes it is. As input I am testing with only one address. I created that address with blockchain.info and has taken the unencrypted HEX from there only. Also cross checked the HEX with bitcore.io/playground/#/address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused becasue BlockCypher-php-client-1.2.2 does not support uncompressed public keys.

Details: https://github.com/blockcypher/php-client/issues/5